# About to apply for a US visa? Can I get an expedited/emergency interview appointment before "First Available Appointment" if I have an emergency?

Tags: usa

I have submitted a DS-160 form and I'm now applying for appointment. I am on the payment page and I'm about to pay the $160 fee. A box on the left side of the page says "First Available Appointment Is Monday January 22, 2018."

However, I need to get to the US before January 22, and I have document evidence to prove this (I'm applying for an F1 visa and college term begins January 23rd). I am certain that an urgent appointment will be needed. Can I appeal/ask for an appointment before this January 22 date?

Can you please tell me the procedure for emergency/urgent appointment process?

Thank you.

Comment: Emergency normally means something unpredictable such as a funeral. The start of university term is known a long time in advance so you should have planned for it. However, you should try anyway since you don't lose much (just the urgent appointment application fee) if they say no.

Comment: First step should probably be to talk to the international students office at the college. The level of knowledge at such offices varies, but you certainly won't be the first student they've had in this situation.

Comment: @user16259 What is the process for getting an urgent appointment? My I20 arrived recently and so I wasn't able to apply well in advance. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the procedure, but I would take Zach's advice and ask the college.

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I got my emergency appointment approved and confirmed for a much better date.

Comment: Awesome @user71611. Good luck with your interview!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have a look at their online [doc](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/ht/ht-niv-expeditedappointment.asp). Seems like you may just be eligible. But, first you need to schedule an online appointment.

> Students (F-1, M-1 ), exchange visitor (J-1) who have not been refused
>   a visa in the last 12 months and if there are no online appointments
>   available in time for the expected start date of your program or you
>   are a returning student/exchange visitor.